# IIS web service does NOT access the database

Tags: asp.net, database, web-services, iis

I published my web site to create IIS web service.
but the problem is when I browse my web service by clicking on Browse *:80, it redirect me to my web-service home page which contains the list of my methods. 
But when I choose a method for test, it allows me to enter the inputs but when clicking the invoke button, it gives an error page.
the error is:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Nourah\WebSite1\App_Data\SBMSDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

I searched in the internet to find solution but couldn't. I tried different ways to solve it like the solution here but no result. ![An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file failed in Vb.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558415/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-failed-in-vb-net)

Maybe it occur because I choose to Detach the database when publishing the website!! but still I have to do that because if I don't Detach the database, Visual Studio show an error and it doesn't publish the website.

I don't know how to solve this problem. 
please help me..

Answer (score 0):

You need to have "User Instance=True;" in your connection string.

```
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLExpress or your instance    name;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory or path of filename|youfilename.mdf;"/></connectionStrings>
```

Comment: can you paste your connection string?

Comment: <add name="sbms" connectionString="Data       Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Nourah\WebSite1\App_Data\SBMSDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

Comment: You are missing userInstance=true semicolon

Comment: now it shows me this error: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: The entry 'sbms' has already been added. (C:\Users\Nourah\Desktop\myWS\web.config line 33)

Comment: You are using sbms two times.http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/23d02d5d-92b8-4a1e-9ea0-74b5c8b89e8c/webconfig-and-the-entry-key-has-already-been-added?forum=netfxsetup change to something diffrent

Comment: Should I chang it in the website (Visual Studio) or in the folder of the web-service? or in both?

Comment: if you have two entries in two web.config change it in one

Comment: it shows me this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Nourah\WebSite1\App_Data\SBMSDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: Dude is this files is already there or you are creating that? because its trying to create a new file

Comment: I have two web.config. the first one I created it. but the second one is already created.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49749/discussion-between-jalpesh-vadgama-and-user3287580)